# Spring MVC and QueryDsl - returning a QTuple gives blank rendering

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, querydsl

In a Spring Boot / Spring MVC application, in a controller I have a very nice query that returns a `List<Tuple>` from QueryDsl.  The return value is being populated correctly (as shown in my debugger), but when it is returned from the controller, the JSON that is returned looks like this:

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

That is, a list of empty objects (instead of showing the tuples).

Is there any way to fix this so that the Tuple's from QueryDsl are serialized correctly to the JSON result sent from the controller?

**NOTE:** I had *jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false*.  When I removed that, I got the following error:

```
No serializer found for class com.querydsl.core.types.QTuple$TupleImpl and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

Is there a way to create a serializer for the QTuple?